# Monotouch derived class from a native class

Tags: objective-c, binding, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to derive a native class compiled from iCarousel native library ( used the LinkWith method described in [this example](http://dantes-andreea.blogspot.com/2012/01/how-to-use-objective-c-library-in.html) ).
When using the generated binding everything works perfectly:

```
iCarousel carousel = new iCarousel( new RectangleF(0, 0, 300, 300) );
```

But when trying to create this derived class:

```
public class Carousel2 : iCarousel
{

    public Carousel2( RectangleF rect ) : base(rect)
    {
            Console.WriteLine("do something");
    }

}
```

and using it like this:

```
Carousel2 carousel = new Carousel2( new RectangleF(0, 0, 300, 300) );
```

It compiles but it just stops working, with no error.  Is it something I'm missing?

UPDATE: I've put the objective-c header and the ApiDefinition.cs source code here:
http://dantes-andreea.blogspot.com/2012/02/icarousel-monotouch-binding-code.html

Comment: Are your bindings available to review (browse or download) anywhere ? e.g. github

Comment: I've put the objective-c header and the apidefinition.cs file here: http://dantes-andreea.blogspot.com/2012/02/icarousel-monotouch-binding-code.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to pass -e to btouch when generating the bindings, otherwise they will not be subclassable.

By default btouch does not generate subclassable types because they're a little bit slower.

**Update**

I was wrong, the -e switch must *not* be passed to btouch to generate subclassable bindings. Unfortunately this switch is passed unconditionally. A [bug report](http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=3234) has been filed.

You can probably work around it by manually running the btouch command after MonoDevelop has built the project (you build the bindings project, c&p the btouch command line and remove the -e switch). Then you'll also have to run any subsequent steps manually too.

Comment: Hy. Does LinkWith have an attribute for this?

Comment: Actually it's the reverse, -e should not be passed. Unfortunately this isn't possible with a bindings project right now.