# MonoTouch binding objc library problems (can't derive from bound objc class)

Tags: objective-c, binding, xamarin.ios, static-libraries

I currently try to create a monotouch binding library for Sparrow 1.3. Everything works fine so far except that I can't derive from a bound objc class like:

```
public class GameStage : SPStage {
    public GameStage() : base() { }
    public GameStage(float width, float height) : base(width, height) { }
}
```

`SPStage` is a class defined in `libSparrow.a`.

`SPStage` seems to be bound properly since the following code works in my example monotouch project:

```
private SPView sparrowView;
...     
RectangleF frame = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds;
SPStage stage = new SPStage(frame.Size.Width, frame.Size.Height);
stage.Color = 0x0000ff;
sparrowView.Stage = stage;
```

But if I try the same with `GameStage`:

```
GameStage game = new GameStage(frame.Size.Width, frame.Size.Height);
game.Color = 0x0000ff;
sparrowView.Stage = game;
```

The application crash with no error or stack trace. The expected result should be a blue screen.

To reproduce the error I have checked in my binding code and the example to git hub. You can clone it from here:

```
git@github.com:goosefx/sparrow-monotouch.git
```

I would be REALLY glad if someone could help me out. I am really stuck with this problem.

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

I first saw a similar question after I wrote this question:
[Monotouch derived class from a native class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9143320/monotouch-derived-class-from-a-native-class)

Removing /e from the mtouch argument list has solved my problem. To bad that MonoDevelop does not support suppressing the /e argument.

To bad that I am not allowed to answer my own question before 8 hours.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Monotouch derived class from a native class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9143320/monotouch-derived-class-from-a-native-class)

Answer (score 1):

The problem i the /e switch MonoDevelop passes to btouch. This can't be disabled through the UI. Currently only a manuel compile helps. See more details here: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=3234